# MVVM example with editable collection where View is not using Model types directly

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have read many people say that model types should not be exposed to View, but instead it should be wrapped inside ViewModel types. Is there some example where I can see how is synchronization done between ViewModel and Model data, using Entity Framework. In particular, I need an example of editable collection (example: DataGrid or DataForm displaying Customer list).

So, something like this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

but with editable collection data, not just read-only.

An example of what I am interested in:

1) a grid needs to show products. 3 columns are shown:

- Product Code
- Product Name
- Product Type
- Product Unit

Type is an Enum, lets say: ProductType { TypeA, TypeB }. If you find difficult to implement enum, then have it a int, its not a problem. Important thing is that Type cannot be changed if Product was already used as reference in somce other table. I am using this rule, since you can not do this with attributes (Data annotations), and needs to be done on ViewModel side.

Each property on a product class must be bound to CustomerViewModel property. You can put some rules for Code and Name:

Code Unique
Name: Required, MaxLength(30)

**EDIT:** my main concern is how we do synchronization between ViewModel and EF Model in batch updates. An example would be:

1) when removing Product, if we remove it from ProductViewModel collection and DBContext, what happens when user decides to cancel (made a mistake or anything)? Do we need to reload all Product from database and recreate all ProductViewModels?

2) user changes product and puts product to invalid state (remember that invalid state is still acceptable for object unless we decide to flush it to database). Then user moves cursor to another product, changes it (this product remains in valid state), and execute save command. What should we do at that point?

I have my solutions for all these questions, but I am not sure if they are correct, are there better ways, so the reason why I asked for other opinions from people that are using this method in daily work.

Comment: Honestly, I think both methods are equally valid and you should use whichever one works best for you. Personally I expose the Model property to the View. Its much less code, and is simpler/easier to work with. The only time I would hide the Model from the View and expose its properties via the ViewModel, is if I was working with a large codebase that has different people working on the different layers.

Comment: Or, as in my case, when values are changed on UI, these values needs to be recalculated / reformatted in ViewModel, before they are stored in model properties. So I need a layer inbetween, and I would like to see some xample how it is proposed to be done.

Comment: I can write you a light, simple example if you want, but could you give me some details first? Like, what kind of "recalculation" needs to be done before storing it in model? I can if you want write you a `DataGrid` sample answering to what you need

Comment: Hi Damascus, I have updated the question

Comment: I created an example for you on github: https://github.com/alexshakurin/EditableDataGridMVVM

Comment: Don't you think this is an effortless question ? you have to try to implement your needs and then get help from here on specific issues that you're stuck in.

Comment: @HichemC I am not asking anyone here to write a program for me. I have asked to see an example of how it should be done with collection-like editing. The only part I am interested in is ViewModel and how data is synchronized. I am not sure how should I have asked a quesiton differently that this? My original question is: "Is there some example where I can see how is synchronization done between ViewModel and Model data.." The key word is synchronization. If you can think you can explain me in plain words how this is done, I have no problem with it.

Comment: Your question says you want to use Entity-Framework, we are to assume that you are using the model(s) as a representation of a table(s)?

Comment: @Alexander I have looked at your examples, and I see that you have covered edit mode. Adding item, I assume, will be similar to this implementation: when AddNewProduct command is issued, we first create new Product, and then create new ProductViewModel. What about removing product? I remove ProductViewModel, and connected product. Then a user decides that a mistake was made and wants to cancel this (batch update). What should then happen? Regarding batch updates: if I change one product and put it in invalid state, move to another valid product, and issue SaveCommand, what should happen?

Comment: @Bob I mentioned EF here only if there are some specific concerns when adding/removing item during batch updates. If however, you think that what you are suggesting can be applied to most ORMs, then EF doesn't need to be a condition. If you look at the example Alexander provided, this is very similar to what I use in my projects, only in my project I have next separation: Data (EF model and DbContext and mappings), Model (repository), ViewModel and View. I am only interested in a part where we need to synchronize CRUD operations on ViewModels with Data (EF Model), especially in batch updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need batch update ability then application needs some updates:

1) Do not call SaveChanges from ProductViewModel. Changes should be saved only on pressing "Save" button

2) In the MainViewModel you need to maintain two additional collections: for new items and deleted items. When user presses "Save" button deleted items will be removed from database and new items will be added to database.

3) When user presses "Cancel" button all changes should be reverted. I.e. all fields should be restored to their original state, deleted items should be added back and new items should be deleted

Please see update on github: https://github.com/alexshakurin/EditableDataGridMVVM

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for all the help so far. I have seen the updated example. The kind of approach you are using here, has raized next question: how will user knoww which record is broken? why do I need to loop through each record (1000 records) to validate it, if I have changed only one? If you look at the EF implementation, before Save it will check for modifed / new objects and display validation error messages for them. Something like that should also exist on ViewModel.

Comment: if we go the root you have taken, we will need to implement something that is simlar to CSLA. Currently in my projects I am using ProductViewModel only as a wrapper to EF Product. This means that when a property is changed, I do a validation that is not possible to be done on EF with Data annotations, and pass immediately value to EF Product. If I need to undo added object, I use EF to just delete it. If I want to undo deleted obect, I use EF to reload only this object. I can also get original value for properties using EF, if required. What is the benefit of approach you have taken?

Comment: If the only benefit is that we can easily switch to different ORM, this is not something that you do often. You choose some ORM because it contains features that other don't, and you rely on those features. Please don't take me wrong, I am not criticizing your work, I am trying to understand why? THanks again for the effort you have provided in building the demos.

Comment: Hi Goran, I think that approach you're currently using is good as well. The reason why I'm not using it is the following: until User hasn't pressed "Save" button no changes are saved to model objects. Consider the following situation: User make changes, these changes are passed to EF entities. After that these entities may be used in other places of application but User may cancel changes to these objects. In this case we'll need somehow to revert all changes (if required).

Comment: As for displaying errors: DataGrid shows red exclamation mark in the left of a row if it is reported any errors via IDataErrorInfo interface. I believe that this is customizable however I've never tried it.